# How can I convert UTF-8 Hex Bytes to Hexadecimal HTML Entities in php?

Tags: php, emoji

While parsing the emails I got stuck with emoji from iphone, and now I am trying to convert **F0=9F=98=8A** to HTML entity like **&#x1f004**.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: You need to provide an unambiguous method for conversion if you hope for any meaningful answers. Right now, an appropriate answer would be to replace the specific string `F0=9F=98=8A` with `&#x1f004`.

Comment: Yes, exactly my major problem is quoted_printable_decode solve my problem but while putting the data into database it's getting truncated.